# removing the form name from post field in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use symfony2 to create a web service.  I'd like the webservice to be structured and listen for:

POST to /teams/list with params key1=value and key2=value2

For validation purposes, i've created a TeamForm object and a TeamFormModel to validate the data against (using annotations).  The problem i'm having is that the form is looking for **team[key1] and team[key2]** instead of just key1 and key2 to bind to the TeamFormModel.

Is there a way to configure the form to not use the team[*]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the **2.1** branch, it's easy you can simply create a form with an empty name.

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
    '',             // the name
    new TeamType(), // the type
    $team           // the data
);
$form->bindRequest($request);
```

So it will work as you are expecting.

But if you are using the **2.0** branch, from what I know, it's not supported and you have to do the binding manually:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TeamType(), $team);
$from->bind($request->request->all());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate entity without creating form. You can create entity object from POST data and pass it to validator. See [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) section of the cookbook.

If you don't like to create entity object from request parameters every time then you can post data in json or xml format and then de-serialize into entity object using [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle).

Comment: Hi @m2mdas, I was actually wondering.. how do you create an entity object from POST data? Meaning, is there a simple way to do it without extracting all parameters individually and using the setters?